# Can a single fragment instance be added simultaneously to more than one container?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Suppose I have an instance of a fragment, as follows:

```
Fragment my_fragment = new MyFragment();
```

Am I allowed to do this?

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.add(R.id.container1, my_fragment, "my_fragment tag");
ft.commit();
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

FragmentTransaction ft2 = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft2.add(R.id.container2, my_fragment, "my_fragment tag");
ft2.commit();
getFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
```

To clarify; I do **not** want 2 separate instances of the `MyFragment` class, I am asking whether a single fragment instance can be added simultaneously to 2 different containers.

In other words: Is it possible to make changes to a fragment in one container and see them reflected in another container in the same fragment at the same time?

Comment: What happens when you try to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Am I allowed to do this?

No.

> I am asking whether a single fragment instance can be added simultaneously to 2 different containers

No, for the same reason you cannot have a `View` simultaneously in two separate containers. Each `View` has a single parent; each content `View` managed by a fragment has a single parent.

> Is it possible to make changes to a fragment in one container and see them reflected in another container in the same fragment at the same time?

No. You are welcome to have two instances of the fragment that talk to one another, perhaps via an event bus, so that changes in one can be reflected as changes in another.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't add same Fragment to multiple containers. If you try to do so, following exception will be thrown. The reasons are explained by [above post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23037857/2083078).

```
if (containerViewId != 0) {
    if (fragment.mFragmentId != 0 && fragment.mFragmentId != containerViewId) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Can't change container ID of fragment "
                + fragment + ": was " + fragment.mFragmentId
                + " now " + containerViewId);
    }
    fragment.mContainerId = fragment.mFragmentId = containerViewId;
}
```